# How can i change the thumbImage in Arkit app?

Tags: ios, textures, arkit

I cannot change the texture of an object from app. I set the texture like that in MainViewController when I press a button:          currentObject?.thumbImage = UIImage(named: "texture")

class Mirror: VirtualObject {

```
override init() {
    super.init(modelName: "mirror", fileExtension: "scn", thumbImageFilename: "mirror", title: "Mirror")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}   //Here i have the init method.
```

Can you tell me please how to update the model`s texture in real time in app?

Comment: Are you asking how to change the contents of an SCNMaterial?

Comment: Do you use SceneKit for rendering 3D objects? If so, you can use code like this: 

let node = SCNNode()
...
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "texture")

Comment: The problem is: when I press the button to change the texture, the texture doesn`t change :/

Comment: let object = VirtualObjectsManager.shared.getVirtualObjectSelected()
        object?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "texture") this is how I do it

Comment: VirtualObjectsManager.shared.virtualObjectSelected?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black
        VirtualObjectsManager.shared.virtualObjectSelected?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIColor.black
        VirtualObjectsManager.shared.virtualObjectSelected?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = UIColor.black
        VirtualObjectsManager.shared.virtualObjectSelected?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.normal.contents = UIColor.black
        I`ve tried like that as well and the object`s texture still do not change in real time in app.